# cakephp throws error while deleting from self referencing table

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have a table with non-unique key referencing primary key. When I delete records by using the same non-unique column in where clause, cakephp joins the same table with same alias that causing SQL error.

```
$this->MyModel->deleteAll(array('non_uniq_id'=>array_keys($data)));
```

I get MySQL error as follows:

```
SQL Error: 1066: Not unique table/alias:...
```

I tried long time to fix it with cakephp's ORM (I can avoid it with my own SQL queries). I also tried [this solution](http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/sql_error_1066_not_unique_table_alias), but it doesn't help.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you'll probably have this problem often, you should make sure your associations and models all have unique names.

Failing that, you can unbind the troubling association temporarily, which should cause it not to be joined:

```
$this->MyModel->unbindModel(array('hasMany' => array('MyModel')));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but ti didn't work. I just removed those association from model, now it works.